# Extension to excited states of Lieb's Theorem for the Hubbard model

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, many-body

[Lieb's theorem](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.1201) shows that for the Hubbard model,
$$\hat{H} = -t \sum_{ \langle \mu,\nu \rangle, \sigma} \hat{c}^\dagger_{\mu \sigma}\hat{c}_{\nu \sigma} + U \sum_\mu \hat{n}_{\mu \uparrow}\hat{n}_{\mu \downarrow},$$
(here $\langle \mu, \nu \rangle$ means sum over first-neighbors) if the lattice of atomic sites $\mu$ is bipartite (so that it can be divided in two sublattices, $A$ and $B$, in a way that sites belonging to sublattice $A$ only have as neighbours sites of sublattice $B$ and viceversa), then the exact ground state has a total spin related to the lattice imbalance:
$$<\Psi_0 | \hat{S}^2 | \Psi_0> = \vert \displaystyle \dfrac{  \vert A \vert - \vert B \vert }{2}\vert,$$
where $\Psi_0$ is the exact many-body ground state of the Hubbard hamiltonian. In particular, this theorem shows that when there is not lattice imbalance ($|A|-|B|=0$) the ground state must always be a singlet.

**Question:** I have observed numerically for many examples that, in the case of no lattice imbalance, not only the ground state is a singlet (as the theorem predicts) but also the **first excited state** is always a **triplet**. However, Lieb's argument cannot be adapted to the excited state. Is there a general argument relating the spin state of the excited states and $|A|-|B|$, at least for the case $|A|-|B|=0$?